# Testing HATEOAS URLs

Tags: rest, testing, hateoas

I'm developing a service that has a RESTful API. The API is JSON-based and uses [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) for HATEOAS links between resources.

The implementation shouldn't matter to the question, but I'm using Java and Spring MVC.

Some example requests:

**`GET /api/projects`**

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "example.org/api/projects"
    },
    "projects" : [ {
      "href" : "example.org/api/projects/1234",
      "title" : "The Project Name"
    }, {
      "href" : "example.org/api/projects/1235",
      "title" : "The Second Project"
    } ]
  },
  "totalProjects" : 2,
}
```

**`GET /api/projects/1234`**

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "example.org/api/projects/1234"
    },
    "tasks" : [ {
      "href" : "example.org/api/projects/1234/tasks/543",
      "title" : "First Task"
    }, {
      "href" : "example.org/api/projects/1234/tasks/544",
      "title" : "Second Task"
    } ]
  },
  "id" : 1234,
  "name" : "The Project Name",
  "progress" : 60,
  "status" : "ontime",
  "targetDate" : "2014-06-01",
}
```

Now, how should I test GET requests to a single project? I have two options and I'm not sure which one is better:

1. Testing for `/api/projects/{projectId}` in the tests, replacing `{projectId}` with the id of the project the mock service layer expects/returns.
2. Requesting `/api/projects/` first then testing the links returned in the response. So the test will not have `/api/projects/{projectId}` hardcoded.

The first option makes the tests much simpler, but it basically hardcodes the URLs, which is the thing HATEOAS was designed to avoid in the first place. The tests will also need to change if I ever change the URL structure for one reason or another.

The second option is more "correct" in the HATEOAS sense, but the tests will be much more convoluted; I need to traverse all parent resources to test a child resource. For example, to test GET requests to a task, I need to request `/api/projects/`, get the link to `/api/projects/1234`, request that and get the link to `/api/projects/2345/tasks/543`, and finally test that! I'll also need to mock a lot more in each test if I test this way.

The advantage of the second option is that I can freely change the URLs without changing the tests.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is testing a Hypermedia API, then your testing tools need to understand how to process and act on the hypermedia contained in a resource.

And yes, the challenge is how deep you decide to traverse the link hierarchy. Also, you need to account for non-GET methods.

If these are automated tests a strategy would be to organize the tests in resource units. Only test the links returned in the resource under test: a module for projects, and others for project, tasks, task, and so on. This does require some hard-coding of well-known URLs for each module, but allows you to manage the tests more easily around your resource model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about HATEOAS . But what I can say.

You may try a [swat](https://github.com/melezhik/swat) - a perl,curl based DSL for web, rest services test automation. Swat was designed to simplify **URL "juggling"** you probably talking about here. A quick reference for how this could be done by SWAT ( a strait forward way, but there are more elegant solutions ):

```
$ mkdir -p api/project/project_id
$ echo '200 OK' > api/project/project_id/get.txt

$ nano  api/project/project_id/hook.pm

   modify_resource(sub{
     my $r = shift; # this is original rout api/project/project_id/
     my $pid = $ENV{project_id};
     $r=~s{/project_id}{$pid} # dynamically setup route to api/project/{project_id}
     return $r;
   }); 

$ project_id=12345 swat  http://your-rest-api # run swat test suite!
```

A more complicated examples could be found at the [documentation](https://github.com/melezhik/swat).

*(*) Disclosure - I am the tool author.*

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring HATEOAS you can use ControllerLinkBuilder (http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-hateoas/0.19.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/ControllerLinkBuilder.html) for link creation in your tests as described in http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.19.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#fundamentals.obtaining-links. With ControllerLinkBuilder, there is no hard-coded URL-s.

ControllerLinkBuilderUnitTest.java (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/4e1e5ed934953aabcf5490d96d7ac43c88bc1d60/src/test/java/org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/ControllerLinkBuilderUnitTest.java) shows how to use ControllerLinkBuilder in tests.